# Two different operating systems on two different hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have windows 7 installed on my hard drive (installed it as BIOS not UEFI), and I want to buy another hard drive and install ubuntu 16.04 on it through UEFI. When I have both hard drives connected to my motherboard will I be able to choose which OS to boot into when I turn on my computer or would I have to always go into my BIOS and change the boot order?

I was thinking of just installing ubuntu 16.04 on my current hard drive alongside dual boot but I don't know if I can install it through BIOS instead of UEFI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, I don't believe it's possible to have UEFI and a true legacy BIOS, so I am not sure how you would install Ubuntu under UEFI with the case you have outlined.

That said, under traditional BIOS, the boot sequence for a multi-boot system (two or more operating systems) is  passed off to a boot loader which allows you to select the OS to boot so you don't have to mess with the BIOS (boot loaders such as GRUB also work on EFI systems).

In any case, with Windows and Ubuntu (Linux), having them installed on separate hard drives is recommended (though not required). Most boot loaders will display a prompt for the OS to boot as mentioned, but also have configurations that specify which OS to boot by default if none is chosen.